# Transform Heisenberg equation into rotating frame

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, quantum-optics

We consider a two-level system with a ground state $|g\rangle$ and an excited state $|e\rangle$. It is placed at position $\mathbf{r}$ and driven by a coherent field $\mathbf{E}$. Assuming a dissipative system and choosing $\hbar = 1$, the Heisenberg equation reads

$$i \partial_t A = [A, H] + i\mathcal{L[A]},$$

with the effective Hamiltonian

$$H = \omega \ \sigma^\dagger \sigma + (\mathbf{E}^*(\mathbf{r}, t) \cdot \mathbf{d} \ \sigma + \text{H.c.}).$$

Here, $\sigma = |g\rangle\langle e|$ and $\mathbf{d}$ is the atomic dipole moment. The exact form of the  Lindbladian $\mathcal{L}$ is not important for this question.

We can write the time-dependence of the (monochromatic) electric field explicitly

$$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t) = \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) e^{-i \omega_L t},$$

where the laser frequency $\omega_L$ is the frequency of the atomic transition $\omega$ plus a detuning $\Delta$

$$\omega_L = \omega + \Delta.$$

Could someone please explain how to transform the Heisenberg equation to a frame, where the operators rotate with $\omega_L$ such that the time-dependence of the field cancels?